# Permissions needed for NotificationManager

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to set the Ringer to Silent and Do not Disturb to Priority Only using the following

```
AudioManager myAudioMgr = (AudioManager) context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
NotificationManager myNOtificationMgr = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

myAudioMgr.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
myNOtificationMgr.setInterruptionFilter(NotificationManager.INTERRUPTION_FILTER_PRIORITY);
```

I keep getting a security error

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start receiver MyBroadcastReceiver: java.lang.SecurityException: Notification policy access denied

I've added the Access Notification Policy permission to my Manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

Am I missing an additional permission?

Comment: What version of Android? I know in recent version you need to request permission via a dialog before you're able to use. The Manifest permissions are just there for legacy devices and so they can display permission usage on the marketplace.

Comment: Min and Target API are 23

Comment: Have a look at this: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html

Comment: Is this a app or a jar file? Are you trying to launch your app once a certain broadcast has been received?

Comment: You aren't requesting the permission, you're just using the API. You need to request the permission and then WHEN/IF you are granted the permission THEN use your API.

Comment: @JoxTraex According to docs: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/normal-permissions.html the permission is a normal permission. Requesting permission is not required it seems.

Comment: What is the version of the SDK on the device? Because this does make a difference. If the version is < 23, that may explain why you're being denied the permission.

Comment: @JoxTraex Still does not matter. The permission is "NORMAL PERMISSION". The api level makes not difference at all here. This issue is the same as a mock location being enabled.

Comment: I don't see how you say it doens't matter when the documentation SAYS "As of API level 23, the following permissions are classified as PROTECTION_NORMAL" this implies that versions < 23 classify it as potentially dangerous.

Comment: No they don't. Kindly re-read the verbiage correctly. Also check this link which defines "As of". https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=as%20of%20meaning

Comment: As of.. means that it will START being .. anything BEFORE that "as of" is implied as remaining as it was. In this context, meaning dangerous. Hence why people are saying that it exists as a previous permission that can be granted by the user. Please read the documentation correctly.

Comment: Check here. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html. the ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY was ADDED in API 23 making your observation moot.

Comment: Either way the verbiage is correct. As for the policy .. there seems to be some confusion as it exists to some as a permission to be granted by the user and the documentation says this isn't needed. So there is some difference that exists. Instead of claiming you're right, @user2511882 accept the ambiguity that exists. If what you are saying WAS true, then there wouldn't be a need to have the user grant the permission.. but it seems that it is still possible. Confusing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the user needs to explicity grant the permission to app via the settings screen in order for the app to manipulate the priority/silent via the notifications api. I am assuming that you are using the notificationManager class for this. Some links that might help you:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED

I think essentially what you need to do is direct the user to the "Show Do Not Disturb access settings" and have him enable the option for notification management (Something similar for what would you do for mock location for example)

Sample code:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(android.settings.NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS), 0);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That the issue exactly!!  Thank you for the Help!

Answer (score 0):

From Android Developers:

> Request policy access by sending the user to the activity that matches
>   the system intent action [ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS).
>
> Use [ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/NotificationManager.html#ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED) to listen for
>   user grant or denial of this access.

So, to get permission you should request policy access by sending the user to the activity that matches the system intent action ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS and listen for response using BroadcastReceiver with action ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_GRANTED_CHANGED.

Also take a look at method isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted() from NotificationManager to check if permission granted.

Answer (score -3):

You'll need to do something like

```
public class SomeFragment extends FragmentCompat {
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        int permissionNotifications = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission. ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY);

        if (permissionNotifications != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                    getActivity(),
                    new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY },
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST
            );
        }
    }
}
```

keep in mind I'm not able to run this code so it may require some TLC but it's a start

Comment: @user2511882 I agree that requesting permission explicitly is not required.  When I check ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission for ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY, I'm getting PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED.

Answer (score -4):

To correct the `java.lang.SecurityException: Access denied to process: 3454` error, `android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER` permission must be added to the Android Manifest.

Add the following line in your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"
```

Comment: How is 'android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER' related to NotificationManager?

Comment: Exactly no where related. @DimaKozhevin