# NoitificationManager permissions

Tags: android, notifications, notificationmanager

I set up a notification using `notification nManager`, but I also know that using notification requires the user to accept the use of it.
Usually those stuff are asked at the beginning of the app, how can I make the small pop-up at app loading to ask him if he wants to get notification or not.

Thanks!

Comment: "I also know that using notification requires the user to accept the use of it" -- there are no permissions required to use `NotificationManager`.

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of iOS. Android apps can show notifications without having to obtain any permission from the user.

Comment: Oh really, I remember that once I entered some apps they used to ask for notification permission.. its no longer needed?

Comment: Yeah maybe I am thinking of IOS.. I used to have an IPhone ages ago haha

Comment: I'm assuming you are talking about this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308512/permissions-needed-for-notificationmanager?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa