# Notification policy error on android error

Tags: c#, android, push-notification, xamarin.android

As you can see on screenshot I have notification policy error.
[image: Object]
But I got every access for notifications, use Google API and logged to my google account at emulator.
[image: Manifest]

What can I do to check my notifications?
Platform: osx, visual studio, lang c#. Emulator: pixel 5, api 33.

Answer (score 0):

This requires "access to Do Not Disturb configuration". You can write the code to prevent this issue. This permission can be requested by starting a configuration activity on mobile:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the related issue about P[ermissions needed for NotificationManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41308697/19335715) you can refet to.